# Is there a canonical example in the Star Trek TNG/Voyager/DS9 era of a junior officer giving a mistake order that a senior must correct?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

I know that there are lot of examples of senior officers doing something and then a junior dramatically shouts "Belay that order!". What I'm talking about is a situation in which a junior officer gives an order thinking it's the right move but that is an obvious mistake that has to be corrected.

Comment: << SENIOR  officers doing something and then a JUNIOR dramatically shouts "Belay that order!". >>  did you get that the wrong way round?

Comment: @Pete no. As an example, "McDuff" in "Conundrum" tries to get one of Picard's orders belayed. Obviously he wasn't REALLY a junior officer, but...

Comment: Okay, it's what you meant to say. But I think it's factually wrong. Usually it's the senior officer overriding a junior officer. A junior overriding a senior would be  a CLM (career limiting move)

Comment: @Pete a junior officer has the authority to stop a senior officer from acting in a way that obviously endangers the ship and crew or otherwise is acting in a way that is against any standing orders.  For instance, when Admiral Pressman, who was ostensibly in charge of the Pegasus mission, was relieved of that command by Picard

Comment: A [search of the transcript site chakoteya.net](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Achakoteya.net+%22belay+that%22) seems to confirm what others have said that it's more common for a senior officer to belay an order made by a junior officer. There are only occasional examples of the reverse, like the example above with MacDuff, or Decker belaying Kirk's order to use a phaser on an asteroid in Star Trek: The Motion Picture, or Troi belaying an order Riker made to the ship's computer in Hollow Pursuits, or Captain Janeway belaying an order by Admiral Janeway from the future in Endgame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the episode [*VOY: Equinox*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Equinox_(episode)), Chakotay orders a more junior officer to relinquish his weapon in order to show an alien species that they're friendly. Janeway overrides his order and insists that they keep their weapons on them.

> **CHAKOTAY:** *Set your weapons down.*
>
> **PARIS:** *Commander?*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *Somebody's got to start trusting somebody around here.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Belay that order. I appreciate your optimism, but in this case, weapons.*

Given that the aliens promptly attack the crew, putting down their weapons would have been a very clear (and easily predicted) mistake.

---

In [*TNG: Redemption, Part II*](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/201.htm), *Captain* Data's First Officer clearly violates Starfleet protocol and gives orders to various junior officers without seeking his Captain's permission, forcing Data to reprimand him.

It's arguable that these orders were the correct course of action at the time (since Data subsequently orders him to do these things) but he could just as easily have disagreed with them.

> **DATA:** *You have taken the phaser and torpedo control units offline.*
>
> **HOBSON:** *Keith, you and I will start bringing the radiation...*
>
> **DATA:** *Mister Hobson, it is inappropriate for you to determine a course of action without consulting the commanding officer.*
>
> **HOBSON:** *I was trying to safeguard the lives of people on those decks, but you're right. Belay those orders, everyone. Phasers and
> torpedoes are back online. What should we do, sir?*
>
> **DATA:** *You will take the phasers and torpedo units offline and begin repairs of the starboard power coupling.*